# Is it possible to save a console command as a favorite or a keyboard shortcut, so I can run it multiple times in a row quickly?

Tags: console, microsoft-edge, chromium, developer-tools

I have a script I need to run multiple times in a row, with a few seconds in between. However, I need to keep reopening the f12 menu after I switch to a new page that I need to run it on. Is there a way to program it as a favorite or a keyboard shortcut so I can just click that instead of f12 then up then enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the developer tools don't have this option to save the console command as a favorite or a keyboard shortcut.

Here are some DevTools Keyboard Shortcuts, you could try to copy the command to the clipboard, then using the keyboard shortcuts to open the console command, and paste the command and run it.

To open DevTools, press the following keyboard shortcuts while your cursor is focused on the browser viewport:

Open whatever panel you used last: `F12 or Control+Shift+I`

Open the Console panel: `Control+Shift+J`

More detail information about the keyboard shortcuts, please check these links:

[Microsoft Edge DevTools Keyboard Shortcuts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/shortcuts#console-panel-keyboard-shortcuts)

[Get Started With Running JavaScript In The Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/console/javascript)